# Why is it considered rude to use all capitals to ask/answer a question?

Tags: discussion, deletion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I'm asking a serious question, sometime the warning even show up when it's not capital letters in the description but equation. For example, even if I just type in

$A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2+E^2+F^2+G^2=H^2$

in a new question thread I still get a message

> DON'T SHOUT! All-caps posts are considered rude and will be quickly deleted.

which I don't get it. Can anyone explain why the system needs to ban ALL CAPITALS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you google for "internet etiquette", you will find that using all-caps is considered shouting, which means that you are trying to get more attention than others around you by being annoying. This, of course, aside from being rude, is downright unfair to people who are trying to get attention by *not* being annoying.

Of course, if you get a "don't shout!" warning just because of an equation with too much capitalized letters, you should dismiss the warning.